# Android, Retrofit , & RxJava: "Realm access from incorrect thread"

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

I have a realm object stored locally that I need to change > then upload to my backend. So inside userService.updateUser() I get my current user object by calling:  Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance() and passing that User object on to my retrofit2 call, but I get the Realm error:

**Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.**

So I'm subscribing on Schedulers.newThread() and observing on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() so I'm thinking thats why the error is thrown...how can I avoid this issue?

```
mCompositeDisposable.add( userService.updateUser()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<User>(){
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(User user) {

                                if(mProgressDlg != null)  mProgressDlg.dismiss();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                if(mProgressDlg != null)  mProgressDlg.dismiss();
                                alertDlg.showIt(mResources.getString(R.string.err_saving_profile),
                                        stringFormatter.getApiErrorMsg(t), "",
                                        "", mParentActivity, JAlertDialog.POSITIVE,null);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() { }
                        }));
```

Comment: rtfm, RealmObject could be accessed only on the same thread, if you need to get items you can copyFromRealm or use same scheduler

Comment: `observeOn()` passes your user proxy obtained on `Schedulers.newThread()` onto `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, but you can only use a managed realmObject on the thread where the Realm instance it belongs to was opened.

Comment: @Viktor Yakunin.  How do you use copyFromRealm?

Comment: All instances that Realm generates cannot be accessed on other threads. You should pass primary keys or other identifiers to other threads and query same objects on other threads by PKs or other identifiers. 

Although instances are not shared among threads, data are shared among threads. Querying same data on other threads doesn't spend time and you can access them immediately.

Comment: for better understanding https://medium.com/@Miqubel/caching-with-realm-and-rxjava-80f48c5f5e37

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add( userService.updateUser( Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(mUser)  )
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeWith
   ...
```

Comment: at least wrap the `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` with `try-with-resources`

Comment: Why the downvote? It did solve my problem. If you are going to downvote at least post a working answer to go along with your comment.

Comment: Because you're opening unclosed Realm instances. If this happens on a background thread - which it does, as it's on `Schedulers.newThread()` - then it'll result in very large Realm file. But I will remove the downvote if you replace `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` with `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { .. }`